# Linux IDE with proper support for STL debugging

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, stl, eclipse-cdt

I am looking for a Linux IDE with support for STL debugging.

the problem is that with Eclipse CDT, if I inspect the vector after the push_back:

```
int main() {
 vector<string> v;
 v.push_back("blah");
 return 0;
}
```

I get something hostile like

```
{<std::_Vector_base<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x1fee040, _M_finish = 0x1fee048, _M_end_of_storage = 0x1fee048}}, <No data fields>}
```

instead of something like

```
vector["blah"]
```

or something similar.
is there an alternative IDE/Debugger for linux that provides better STL support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) has debugger dumpers for the Qt containers, some of the STL containers and a bunch of the Qt classes. It's also more responsive than Eclipse.

See [Qt Creator debugger dumpers](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/06/22/peek-and-poke/).

Comment: interesting, downloading to check it out.

Comment: using QTC 1.2.1 with the above code (without any QT components), I still get the classical crappy vector display.

Comment: It's possible that the dumpers are not built. Go to Tools > Options > Qt > Qt Versions and select your Qt version. See if the debugging helper is marked as build (green checkmark) and if not try to rebuild it. If everything is ok, when running GDB you will get a message "X debugger helpers loaded" on the debugger info bar.

Comment: the debugging helper were indeed not built, I built it successfully but I still don't get it to work. you mean that when I run GDB from the command line I am supposed to get that "X debugger helpers loaded" message?

Comment: Sorry: after you press F5 to start debugging and the debugger stops at a breakpoint (or you do an interrupt), the debugger view will have a gray status bar with start/stop/etc buttons. This bar should display "X custom dumpers found" if it was able to load the debugging helpers. Make sure you have them turned on from Tools > Options > Debugging helpers and that you're running a debug build.

Comment: Alternative way to check: right click the locals and watches debug tab while stopper at breakpoint and click "recheck debugging helper...". The debugger tab should list what helpers it found: eg: \"tdumpers=[\\\"QAbstractItem\\\",\\\"QAbstractItemModel\\\",\\\"QByteArray\\\", etc.

Comment: looks like this only works for QT GUI applications (my original test was a basic QT4 console app). this is a bit too tied up for my liking but I accept it as an answer because it's the closest one to what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

Just a matter of scripting GDB so you can print stl containers.
To print a vector:

```
define pvec
    set $vec = ($arg0)
    set $vec_size = $vec->_M_impl->_M_finish - $vec->_M_impl->_M_start
    if ($vec_size != 0)
        set $i = 0
        while ($i < $vec_size)

          printf "Vector Element %d:  ", $i

          p *($vec->_M_impl->_M_start+$i)

          set $i++

        end
    end
end
```

Now you can even script it on python. Check the documentation.

I personally use cgdb which is a very convenient curses debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This has got nothing to do with the IDE per se, but this is a drawback of the debugger you are using. IDEs, especially on Linux, are just front-ends for debuggers. I suppose you are using GDB, and it won't get any better than this. BTW, while developing on Linux, I use carefully placed print statements instead of a debugger and most of the time I find it better than using a debugger!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse use gdb and you can script gdb so it print different types the way you want. I use my own scripts for my own types but there is many available scripts for the stl.

Now the tricky part will be to make this work smoothly is Eclipse, but it can be a solution.

Comment: I am aware of some scripts that improves gdb support for stl, but I am after a full solution.

as you said - those scripts does not integrate well with any IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay away from GDB scripts you might as well leave Eclipse in favor of [QtCreator](https://www.qt.io/download) or if you don't mind paying for a license [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) is the best IDE around IMO.